# Javascript from a URL

Tags: javascript, css, json, dom, vertical-alignment

Suppose I need to shift an image vertically and I do it with code like this

```
document.getElementById('ImgID1').style.verticalAlign =
```

However, the amount by which I need to shift the image comes from a URL (I give the URL below,if you like to look at it), such that if I were to execute the contents of the URL as javascript, the result is `"-8px"` which is what I want? But how in the world do I accomplish this? How do I say `verticalAlign={grab the url, execute as JS, take the return value}`.

The URL is [http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.json?\inline%20\mathbb{R}](http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.json?%5Cinline%20%5Cmathbb%7BR%7D)

Sample response:

```
ParseEqn({ "latex": { "type":"gif", "equation":"\\mathbb{R}", "site":"stackoverflow.com", "file":"f3ed131812d10a06a9349ab2b42e3ed4.gif", "url":"http://www.codecogs.com/eq/f3/f3ed131812d10a06a9349ab2b42e3ed4.gif", "width":"12", "height":"12", "baseline":"1" } });
```

Many thanks in advance!

Sam

Comment: You could use AJAX to get the JSON. I would recommend using jQuery with its `$.get` function, that's exactly what you're searching for. By the way the URL is the address (http://...), not the website. What you need to get is a website, in this case, a JSON string.

Comment: That's a JSONP response. So make a proper JSONP request, and all is well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the fiddle to get response from the server. Open console to verify the same.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/softvar/uafYu/)** : **JQUERY way**

```
window.ParseEqn = function(data) {
alert(data.latex.type);
}

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.json?%5Cinline%20%5Cmathbb%7BR%7D',
    crossDomain: true,

    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    headers: {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": '*'
             },  
})
```

**JAVASCRIPT way: solution proposed by [Blue skies](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2860523/blue-skies)**

```
window.ParseEqn = function(data) {
    alert(data.latex.width);
}

var s = document.createElement("script")
s.src = "http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.json?%5Cinline%20%5Cmathbb%7BR%7D";
s.onload = function() {
    document.body.removeChild(s);
};
document.body.appendChild(s);
```

Comment: Why do you think it's not valid JSONP? And why are you posting a jQuery solution?

Comment: I checked both your fiddles. The `ParseEqn(...)` is what makes it valid JSONP. The server is just not set up to send a dynamic function name. And it would be foolish to suggest jQuery for something as small and simple as this. Please don't whine about people not elaborating when it took you 15 minutes to reply to my questions and only did so after I finally gave the down vote.

Comment: Fine.. can you suggest a way then

Comment: I was the first to post an answer, which worked perfectly. I deleted my answer because OP posted a question and then disappeared. I don't like helping people like that.

Comment: Perfect solution...misunderstood jsonp. But surprised why you deleted that.

Comment: If you update your answer to include a native JSONP solution like I had, I'll remove the downvote.

Comment: @BlueSkies: what do you mean by "OP Disappeared"?

Comment: @SamTakoy: You posted a question, received comments and answers, but gave no interaction for hours. Disappeared.

Comment: @BlueSkies - Different timezone. Had to sleep. Anyway, your answer worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can to use AJAX to get file JSON and in you case:

```
$.getJSON('gif.json', function(data) {
```

I not think that when you put the url the function goes for download and works.

```
var im = document.createElement("IMG")
```

document.body.appendChild(s); 
    $.getJSON('http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.json?\inline%20\mathbb{R}', function(data) {
          var items = [];

```
      $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        if(key=="url")
        im.src=value;
        else if (key="width")
        im.style.width=value;
        else if (key="heigth")
        im.style.heigth=value;
              });
    document.getElementById("yourdive's case").appendChild(im);
    });
```

I think that this you are looking for this